# javascript make Array [n] automatically

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers

If I have an array:

```
var imgArray = New Array();

imgArray[0] = "example_A"
imgArray[1] = "example_B"
imgArray[2] = "example_C"
imgArray[3] = "example_D"

...

imgArray[n] = "example_n"
```

and my javascript sheet is:

```
var imgArray = New Array();

imgArray[0] = "example_A"
imgArray[1] = "example_B"
imgArray[2] = "example_C"
imgArray[3] = "example_D"

...

imgArray[n] = "example_n"


var linkArray = New Array();

linkArray[0] = "example_A"
linkArray[1] = "example_B"
linkArray[2] = "example_C"
linkArray[3] = "example_D"

...

linkArray[n] = "example_n"

function diceCast(){return Math.floor(Math.random()*n+1);};
function showImage(){
        
var imgNum = diceCast();
var objImg = document.getElementById("mainImg");
objImg.src = imgArray[imgNum];
objImg.onclick = ()=>window.open(linkArray[imgNum], '_blank');
 }
```

How can I make array number '[n]' automatically?

Comment: check Array.fill for more

Comment: @Codenewbie fill doesn't work in this case, since `fill` is used to add a value to all array elements

Comment: What could be the size of array? Is there any max number.

Comment: yeah makes sense ...

Comment: @decpk I'll number them every time I add the data. so... max number could be changed every time.

Comment: .push() method will always put the item you give it at the end of the array, if you are looking for that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to change diceCast to include the `imgArray.length` instead of using `n`

```js
var imgArray = [
  'https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/f00',
  'https://dummyimage.com/100x100/f00/000'
]

var linkArray = [
  'https://example.com',
  'https://google.com'
]

const diceCast = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArray.length)

function showImage(){     
  var imgIndex = diceCast()
  var objImg = document.getElementById("mainImg")
  objImg.src = imgArray[imgIndex]
  objImg.onclick = () => {
    console.log('opening', linkArray[imgIndex])
    window.open(linkArray[imgIndex], '_blank')
  }
}

showImage()
```

```html
<img id=mainImg>
```

Answer (score -2):

I believe that you can achieve the desired effect through the following code snippet:

```
function getArray(n){
  var arr = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
    arr.push("example_" + String.fromCharCode(65 + i)); // Start from 'A'

  }
  return arr;
}
console.log("Array: %o", getArray(10));
```

EDIT:
In case `n` exceeds the alphabet/printable chars you may prepend as HEX e.g.

```
arr.push("example_" + (10 + i).toString(16));
```

Comment: I doubt they want this kind of urls. it's just example strings

Comment: If the length of the array is bigger, it will return some random String such as ```]``` in the array.